# Save Excel sheet to pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have a macro that would save a sheet to pdf format but it doesn't work anymore.

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .CenterHeader = strFile2
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .PrintArea = "a1:q21"
    '.PrintTitleRows = ActiveSheet.Rows(5).Address
    '.Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With    

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=strFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

I tried

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating
```

It gives the same

> invalid procedure call or argument.

The macro works at my colleague's PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared variables outside of the snippet of code you pasted? You need to declare ws as a worksheet or you are going to have issues:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
```

You need to set ws = ActiveSheet in order to use it, though I would recommend avoiding ActiveSheet since it can lead to issues. Something better would be:

```
Set ws = Workbooks("**Name of your workbook**").Worksheets("**Name of worksheet**")

With ws.PageSetup
**code**
End With
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi, it was commented :D from a previous modification . Thank you for the answer.